# I am creating an application which is integrated with paypal. I want to make the token key dynamic from database in web config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, web-config

I am creating an application which is integrated with paypal. I want to make the token key which is there in the app setting in web config file dynamic from the database.I tried it by the below code:

```
`Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
string oldValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["token"].Value;
        config.AppSettings.Settings["token"].Value = "abc";
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        string newValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["token"].Value;`
```

This above code change the token key in the main web config file.I want to ask that if two different users use my application with different token key of paypal,is there any conflict happen?

Comment: what is the purpose of your token ? is it generated by PayPal or is it a token for each and every users ?

Comment: 1) Are you referring to the PDT token?
2) If I understood correctly you read a token from a database and then save this value into the web.config, right?
2) Where/When do you execute that code?

Comment: Yes, this token is generated by Paypal.

Comment: Yes, its a PDT token. I execute this above code in constructor.

Comment: I meant if you execute that code every time that an user send a Paypal transaction. However in my opinion is not a good approach because the PDT is a "static" identity token of the Paypal account that will receive money, so why do you need to read it from the database and to re-write it on the Web.config every time? Do you have to switch to different  "destination" Paypal account? Anyway if you are executing, for example, that code during a click action it will be executed, on the server side, for each click: that is why I asked to you where/when you execute that code.

Comment: My application is based on the id which user punched in the url. suppose there are two companies Company A and Company B. Compnay A started a Program A and Company B started a Program B. Both companies have the registration form Registration Form A and Registration Form B. Both the registration form have the url (URL A?id=1) and (URL B?id=2).For (URL A?id=1) the paypal destination is different and for (URL B?id=2) is different.So according to the id i want to change the PDT.

Comment: Both the registration form are same, only the layout changed according to the id entered.

Comment: On the page load my application check the Id that which layout is to start then it forwarded.

Comment: The Web.config file and its AppSettings element have an Application Configuration Purpose, so if your PDT token has to change for each logged/registered user, this file is not the right place to store this data and therefore, in my opinion, depending of the logic of your code, the probability to have a conflict is very high.
According to me is much better to consider a different solution by storing the User Portal Setting in a table of your db or in a dedicated config setting file created dynamically during the registration process of each company that wants to start a program on your web app.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try this. Thanks Domenico, Thanks for your help.